# Protect client-server communication from leaks

Tags: php, android, piracy

I'm developing an android application that communicates with my server. That server provide information through a get (or post), and the application display these information.

The question I want to make is if it's possible to make this connection "safe", I mean, I want to provide information only to the user who use MY application.
I make an example, I've a website, if you visit this page:

```
http://mywebsite.com/APP/get.php?a=23123
```

You'll get useful information that i want to display into my app. The problem is that everyone can make it's own app that connect itself to my website, and get these information. Is possible to check via server who is using my application and who is trying to get only the information from another thing that isn't my app?

Comment: try to implement ssl with your own key pair

Comment: starters use SSL, secondly you need to work on an authentication key system where a usr logs in first run of app is provided with a auth key which the phone temp stores and passes with every request if the key doesn't match the user in the DB then it won't provide the information have a cron script auto clear keys if not used in 5 minutes

Comment: I prefer to not implement any login system in my app. It must be a fast app that provide informations fastly.